# Power plane vs polygon pours

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers, power-delivery

This question is being asked from perspective of Altium but applies to other PCB CAD programs as well.

So we can have two type of dedicated copper areas for power on a PCB plane. One is a polygon pour. The other is power plane.

When using polygon pours to distribute the power rails, we can still lay signal tracks on that layer as well.

When using power planes, any polygon or track laid on the plane will remove copper thus power plane is a kind of "negative" layer in that drawing on it removes copper. We can't have signal tracks on a power plane, just not allowed.

I believe that concept of power plane exists due to historic reasons and that since using polygon pours offers more flexibility and control, we should use polygon pours instead. This means that the power layer in the PCB stack-up shall be declared as a signal layer and then we shall layout polygon pours on it. No need to declare it as power plane layer.

Is my understand incorrect?

Comment: Planes are generally an archaic method, yes. "We can't have signal tracks on a power plane, just not allowed" -- track objects per se, no, but that doesn't mean you can't route signals there. It's just more awkward.

Comment: So the concept of negative planes, where we don't route any signals at all is actually a remnant from early PCB design days which does not need to be strictly followed now?

Comment: Typically, impedance calculation is done against them, but IIRC Altium addressed this in recent versions so that you are free either to set reference planes manually, or to automatically detect nearest polygons as reference planes. And you can completely skip impedance calculation by setting trace width manually. You can use either one, doesn't matter, you still get a board in the end.